# SQL Server seems to calculate key length incorrectly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

When trying to create a database running a script generated by Visual Studio (Entity Framework, "Generate Database From Model..." link), I'm running into an error with a Primary Key.

The command giving me an issue is

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD CONSTRAINT constraintname
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (col1, col2 ASC);
```

The error I'm getting is

> Index constraintname was not created. The index has a key length of 1024 bytes. The maximum permissible key length is 900 bytes.

The table is created with

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    col1 nchar(256)  NOT NULL,
    col2 nchar(256)  NOT NULL
);
```

which looks to me to be 512 bytes, not 1024.

What's causing SQL Server to count it as 1024, and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Your columns add up to 512 **characters** - not bytes. Depending on the character set that can yield up 1500 bytes (e.g. with UTF-8).

Comment: `nchar(256)` is pretty unusual anyway. Are all the values fixed width of 256 characters or is that the maximum length?

Comment: @MartinSmith It's fixed-length. They each serve as an ID on other tables. I'm not the one who decided on nchar(256); it's apparently already in use (though I don't see how that would work).

Comment: I can't think of a valid use case for an identifier consisting of 256 unicode characters and unless you can change it you won't be able to create your table with desired constraint. Why would you need an id that long?  A guid is only 16 bytes.

Comment: Turns out there was a discrepancy in some of the documentation. Stats pulled from the live system listed the size in bytes (256) as the length in characters (128).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error caused by inaccurate documentation, not a technical issue.

Comment: 256 byte fixed width ids still seems like a recipe for problems and performance issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`nchar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) is unicode, which takes up two bytes per character.

If you don't need unicode, switch to `char`. Or shorten your columns, or add separate column(s) to use as a key. Two 512 character strings is a pretty large primary key!

Comment: The most important advice is missing: Switch to n*var*char! That way you don't waste 90% of the space and solve the error.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to `nvarchar`. `nchar` is a fixed-space data type. You'll probably waste 90% of your storage space. If you want to store a string of 10 chars you will need space for 256 which is an unnecessary waste.

Consider going to `varchar` to space a further 50%. But you loose Unicode that way.

Next todo for you: read the documentation to familiarize yourself with data types. There are tricky mistakes to be made.

Comment: It should be noted that if any rows do actually have more than 1024 bytes worth of data in their PK fields, this will still fail.

Comment: Did you read the comments? They say it is fixed width (though I can't really envisage what madcap scheme they must be using to generate ids)

Comment: I think he is saying that they are already (mistakenly) using fixed-width types elsewhere. That does not mean he has to do that here as well. Maybe the OP can clarify.

Comment: @usr - This is intended to be a many to many relationship table for ids from two other tables I imagine.

Comment: @MartinSmith I hope those IDs are space-extended. Cannot imagine what a truely 256 character ID would look like. If the OP confirms I'll get rid of that answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    col1 nvarchar(256)  NOT NULL,
    col2 nvarchar(256)  NOT NULL
);
```

EDIT (Sasha.Sochka's request):

nchar uses fixed size of n characters, even if the value could fit in a smaller space. nvarchar uses space for as few characters as possible, while its upper bounds is the space for 256 characters in our case. So, if you have this 'foo', then it will allocate space for 256 characters if it is an nchar and it will allocate space for 3 characters, if it is nvarchar.